# Input do tipo file com a função split() retorna com vírgula

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jsp

Estou recuperando o arquivo retornado de um `input` do tipo `file` de um `form` e ele retorna `C:\\fakepath\\nomedoarquivo.extensão` até aí tudo bem, daí apliquei um `split()` e ele retorna o seguinte: `,nomedoarquivo.extensão` por quê isso acontece e como resolver?
Print do ocorrido: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da minha `JSP`:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>""</title>
        <style>
            .arquivo {
                display: none;
            }
            .file {
                line-height: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                border: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
                padding: 5px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                font-size: 15px;
                vertical-align: middle;
                width: 237px;
            }
            .btn1 {
                cursor: pointer;
                border: none;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 2px 10px;
                background-color: #4493c7;
                color: #FFF;
                height: 32px;
                font-size: 15px;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="modal_file" class="modal-3" onclick="enableDrag(this);">
            <!-- tarja -->
            <div class="tarja"></div>
            <!-- header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <!-- icone -->
                <div class="icon-modal-3">
                    <img src="Pictures/todosIcons.png" alt="search_icon">
                </div>
                <!-- titulo -->
                <div class="title-modal title-blue">
                    <h2>Select a File</h2>
                </div>
                <!-- botao de fechar -->
                <div class="close-button cl-bt-blue" onclick="$('#modal_file').css('display', 'none');">
                    <p>X</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h2>Selecione um arquivo para upload:</h2>
            <form>
                <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo" class="arquivo">
                <input type="text" name="file" id="file" class="file" placeholder="Arquivo" readonly="readonly">
                <input type="button" class="btn1" value="SELECIONAR">
            </form>   

        </div>
        <script src="JS/FormRedirect.js" ></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/dragAndDrop.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
                    $('.btn1').on('click', function () {
                        $('.arquivo').trigger('click');
                    });
                    $(function () {
                        $('.arquivo').on('change', function () {
                            var numArquivos = $(this).get(0).files.length;
                            if (numArquivos > 1) {
                                $('#file').val(numArquivos + ' arquivos selecionados');
                            } else {
                                $('#file').val($(this).val().split('C:\\fakepath\\'));
                            }
                        });
                    });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o `String.split` irá retornar um *array*. Neste caso, o *jQuery* vai utilizar a função `Array.implode` antes de adicionar o valor no `input` (já que ele aceita apenas *string*).

Para corrigir isso, basta informar o índice antes de definir o `value`

**Exemplo:**

```js
const file = $("[type='file']"),
      text = $("[type='text']")
      
$(file).on("change", function() {
  $(text).val( $(this).val().split('C:\\fakepath\\')[1] ); // Utiliza o índice "1"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" />
<br /><br />
<input type="text" />
```

Uma alternativa é usar a propriedade `files` do *input:file*. Com esta propriedade, você pode acessar outros atributos do arquivo, como por exemplo: mimetype¹, tamanho, nome, data de modificação etc.

**Exemplo:**

```js
const file = document.querySelector("[type='file']"),
      name = document.querySelector("#name"),
      type = document.querySelector("#type"),
      size = document.querySelector("#size")

file.addEventListener("input", () => {
  
  //Acessa a propriedade "files" > Captura o primeiro valor do array
  let data = file.files[0]
  
  name.textContent = data.name
  type.textContent = data.type
  size.textContent = `${Math.round(data.size/10000)} MB`
})
```

```html
<input type="file" />
<br /><br />
Name: <span id="name"></span><br>
Type: <span id="type"></span><br>
Size: <span id="size"></span>
```

> ¹: O valor do *mimetype* é definido de acordo com a extensão do arquivo.